# Command-line Input Files (Fizz Buzz)

Tags: file, input, command-line, fizzbuzz

I am trying to brush up on my coding skills, and decided to try some of the problems on codeeval.com. One of the problems is the fizz buzz program. The solution to the problem is found on the link:

http://bipinbudhathoki.blogspot.com/2011/07/fizzbuzz-java-solution-for-codeevalcom.html

I am having trouble understanding how the input file is being read in the solution. How does the program know what file to read in if the name of the file is not stated anywhere in the code? How do command-line argument inputs work in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Scanner console = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[0]));

The `Scanner` is reading from the file specified in `args[0]`, which is the first command line argument.